# Usage of "provided" and "providing"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

I'm not sure if I used the word "provided" in a right way in the following example:

> In general, this algorithm solves Fibonacci problem with higher scores rather than the original algorithm, provided/providing reasonable values are selected for stack size and array length.

In this text I want to say that if user choose reasonable variables then it is rightly expected that the mentioned algorithm works better than the original.

Finally, please can you tell me that are "provided" and "providing" the same? which is better to use for scientific papers?

Comment: You can use both *provided that*, *providing that*. They mean the same.

Comment: Specifically speaking about usage, both are correct and mean the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conversational use, you will encounter both expressions and, as brick notes, *provided that* which is slightly more formal.

In a scientific paper, I would avoid all of these forms. The link **subject to the requirement that** makes the status of the caveat crystal clear. If you wanted a less verbose expression, you might try **so long as** or even **if** or **when**.

Answer (score 1):

In your text you should use **provided** since *reasonable values are selected for stack size and array length* is the condition to respect in order for *the algorithm to solve Fibonacci problem with higher scores*.
The form *providing* is correct but could be mistaken with The Present Continuous Tense of the verb *to provide* which means *to make available for use; to supply*

Comment: One of the shorter garden path sentences, though - the **are selected** soon shows that this is the _subordinator_ incarnation of **providing**. (One could argue that **provided** could also be mistaken for the past participle for an instant).

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using *provided (that)* conjunction. I can't see any reason not to use these constructions:

- on condition that
- assuming that
- given that
- taking into account that ...*and more*...

From what I've seen all of them appear in scientific papers. I agree with Fortiter that you should avoid verbose sentences. Keep it simple.